# keepalived delay before bringing ip up

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication, keepalived, master-master

Is it possible to configure a delay before bringing the virtual IP up in keepalived?

Background:
I have multiple Master/Master MySQL Setups. Only one Master is used at time. Keepalived is used for VIP that is used for mysql traffic. When the VIP is switched to the other master, there should be a delay of 5 seconds before the VIP comes up again. To be sure that the other side has enough time to finish the last replication traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received a reply from Quentin Armitage:

> There is no configuration option that explicitly causes a delay in
> VIPs being configured on a new master, but there are a couple of ways
> I can think of that of that might achieve what you want (of course
> having a delay is completely counter to the purpose of VRRP which is
> about trying to minimise the downtime of a VIP being unavailable).
>
> Option 1.
>
> This will give longer downtime for an outage than for maintenance
> (when I presume that keepalived is shutdown on the existing master).
>
> Configure your VRRP instances to use VRRP version 3, an advert_int of
> 5 seconds, and your two VRRP instances to use priority 1 and priority
> 2 respectively.
>
> In the event of keepalived being stopped on the original master (I
> assume this is what is done for maintenance), it will send a priority
> 0 advert, and since the other instance has priority 1 it will wait
> (256 - 1) / 256 * 5 seconds (i.e. 4.98 seconds) before taking over as
> master (setting the advert_int to 5.02 will give you near enough an
> exact 5 second delay). The disadvantage of this is that if there is an
> outage, it will take between 15 and 19.98 seconds for the backup to
> take over as master.
>
> Option 2
>
> Use a firewall to block access to the VIP until the new master is
> ready.
>
> You could use notify_backup and notify_master scripts to do this, but
> the order of execution of notify scripts is not reliable, so you
> should use a notify_fifo and a script to read the FIFO (see
> vrrp_notify_fifo and vrrp_notify_fifo_script) in keepalived.conf(5)
> man page. There is a sample_notify_fifo.sh script in the doc/samples
> directory in the keepalived source tree, and it may be installed
> somewhere like /usr/share/doc/keepalived by your distro.
>
> When a backup message is received on the FIFO, add a firewall rule to
> drop packets to the VIP. When a master message is received on the
> FIFO, run a script asynchronously that sleeps 5 seconds and then
> removes the firewall rule.

https://groups.io/g/keepalived-users/topic/is_it_possible_to_configure/81962597